# How do I extract full strings that start with a pattern in R

Tags: r, regex

I have data that contains a list of tweets like so:

```
"what is up", "RT @lolol wassup", "RT @joe pls help me"
```

I want to be able to extract the strings that start with RT @, and store it in another list. I'm currently using this:

```
str_extract(data, "^RT[:space:]+@[:graph:]+")
```

But that only extracts the "RT @name" part of the string, not the entire tweet. Can't figure out what's wrong with the regex. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grep` to extract the full string that starts (`^`) with 'RT' followed by a space and `@` in `base R`

```
grep('^RT @', data, value = TRUE)
#[1] "RT @lolol wassup"    "RT @joe pls help me"
```

#### data

```
data <- c("what is up", "RT @lolol wassup", "RT @joe pls help me")
```

Answer (score 0):

`str_extract` extracts the pattern you specify. To get the complete tweet when a pattern is supplied use `str_subset`.

```
library(stringr)
result <- str_subset(data, "^RT[:space:]+@[:graph:]+")
result
#[1] "RT @lolol wassup"    "RT @joe pls help me"
```